# C# XML Deserialization of array

Tags: c#, xml, arrays

I have a problem about deserialize an array. Becouse array elements can be of various types. You can see the example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><export xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/export/1" xmlns:oos="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/types/1">
<notificationZK>
    ... item 1 data
</notificationZK>
<notificationZK>
    ... item 2 data
</notificationZK>
<notificationFF>
    ... item 3 data
</notificationFF>
</export>
```

All elements extends `notificationType`

```
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(notificationSZType))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(notificationPOType))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(notificationZKType))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(notificationEFType))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(notificationOKType))]
    public partial class notificationType
    {
...
```

So the question is how can I get the collection of `notificationType` elements from my XML file? I think I cant do something like

```
[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("export")]
public class NotificationCollection
{
    [XmlArray("")] // ???? what I need write here?
    [XmlArrayItem("", typeof(notificationType))] // ??? and here?
    public notificationType[] notification { get; set; }
}
```

Regards!

ADDED-------------

So. I make this:

```
[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("export")]
public class NotificationCollection
{
    [XmlElement("notificationSZType", Type = typeof(notificationSZType))]
    [XmlElement("notificationPOType", Type = typeof(notificationPOType))]
    [XmlElement("notificationZKType", Type = typeof(notificationZKType))]
    [XmlElement("notificationEFType", Type = typeof(notificationEFType))]
    [XmlElement("notificationOKType", Type = typeof(notificationOKType))]
    public notificationType[] notification { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NotificationCollection collection = null;
        string path = @"E:\notification.xml";
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(notificationType));
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
        collection = (NotificationCollection) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();

    }
}
```

but have System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled while `serializer.Deserialize(reader);`

```
Message=<export xmlns='http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/export/1'> not expected.
```

What im doing wrong?

Comment: The example XML is missing the opening <export> tag.

Comment: Why its missing? Its the real XML from project I working :( Here is the example of real file: http://www.sendspace.com/file/u5bfs7

Comment: Ignore me. I misread :(

Comment: I've tested 3 of your answers and they work.

Comment: But it not work for me :( I generated C# classes from XSD. XSD can be downloaded here http://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/main/public/download/downloadDocument.html?id=100 Possible generated classes are missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job

```
    [Serializable()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("export")]
    public class NotificationCollection
    {
        [XmlElement("notificationSZType", Type = typeof(notificationSZType))]
        [XmlElement("notificationPOType", Type = typeof(notificationPOType))]
        [XmlElement("notificationZKType", Type = typeof(notificationZKType))]
        [XmlElement("notificationEFType", Type = typeof(notificationEFType))]
        [XmlElement("notificationOKType", Type = typeof(notificationOKType))]
        public notificationType[] notification { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: @Gusdor how do i implement this if the elements are unknown? in OP's case, the elements' names are known. in my case i can't do [XmlElement("notificationOKType", Type = typeof(notificationOKType))]
        public notificationType[] notification { get; set; } because the element 'notificationOKType' could have any name

Comment: @wintersolstice this is possible (and straight forward) but you should create another question.

Answer (score 2):

How about moving the type declarations into the collection?

```
[XmlRoot("export")]
public class NotificationCollection
{

  [XmlElement("notificationZK", typeof(NotificationTypeZK))]
  [XmlElement("notificationFF", typeof(NotificationTypeFF))]
  public List<NotificationType> Notifications { get; set; }

}

public class NotificationType
{

}

public class NotificationTypeZK : NotificationType { }

public class NotificationTypeFF : NotificationType { }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var data = @"<export><notificationZK /><notificationZK /><notificationFF /></export>";

  var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NotificationCollection));

  using (var reader = new StringReader(data))
  {
    var notifications = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is interesting for me as well. I wrote the simplified app to achieve what you ask for:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ItemA))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ItemB))]
public class BaseItem
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ItemA : BaseItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ItemB : BaseItem
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ItemsArray
{
    public BaseItem[] Items { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var array = new ItemsArray
        {
            Items = new BaseItem[]
            {
                new ItemA { Value = true, Text = "Test" },
                new ItemB { Value = false, Number = 7 }
            }
        };

        ItemsArray output;

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ItemsArray));
            serializer.Serialize(stream, array);

            stream.Position = 0;
            output = (ItemsArray)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

After deserialization we get exactly what we serialized. The XML inside stream looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ItemsArray xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Items>
    <BaseItem xsi:type="ItemA">
      <Value>true</Value>
      <Text>Test</Text>
    </BaseItem>
    <BaseItem xsi:type="ItemB">
      <Value>false</Value>
      <Number>7</Number>
    </BaseItem>
  </Items>
</ItemsArray>
```

As was mentioned in other answer, you can't use different tags inside XML array. However, it's still possible to store different types. Serializer does this by using `xsi:type` attribute.

In order to solve your problem you probably need to use a bit another scheme of XML.

Comment: If the format of the export isn't fixed, I'd use such an approach as well.

Comment: Depending on your schema, it is valid XML to have varying child element tag names. It is possible to solve this problem while retaining the schema defined in the question.